# Can one start a Process on record delete?

Tags: flow, process-builder

I have a flow which populates a lookup field on Opportunity when and Opportunity Team Member record is inserted. I'd like to create another process to set the lookup field to null if an Opportunity Team Member is deleted. It's not clear to me how to use record deletion to start a Process. Is this possible?

Comment: you need trigger for sure

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I'd suspected. Perhaps a future release will support more contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add some specificity to the comment you received, if the Opportunity Team Member was being deleted from the `OpportunityTeamMember` Object, you'd need an AfterDelete trigger that fired on `OpportunityTeamMember`. The trigger would then need to collect the User IDs of deleted members to use in the `WHERE` clause of a Query on `Opportunity` to find the Opportunity Records which need to be updated.