# Is there an Alternative of 'After Delete' Trigger?

Tags: delete, after

I want to perform an action (say some calculations)after a delete operation. Can this be achieved in any way other than an after delete trigger ?

Comment: question is not clear. It would be easier to help if you put some info what you need to achieve, what did you try and why that have failed

Comment: Actually I have an object (Child)in which if someone deletes a record I want a field in the Parent object to be updated. Now this can't be done through workflow field update since field updates don't fire on delete so I was thinking of writing a trigger. Is there any thing other than trigger I can use to do this?

Comment: Is it a Master-Detail relationship? Because if so you could do a roll-up summary, maybe.

Comment: Yes it is MD relationship but this how will I achieve this with Roll-Up summary? With rollup summary I can refer child from parents. Here I want a field update on parent after deleting a child record.

Comment: what field do you want to update and with what value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If deletion of a child sobject should update a parent with something that can't be calculable from a RSF on the parent (like a count of details, or sum of detail amounts), you are faced with:

**Option 1 - Trigger**

Write an after delete trigger on the child to perform some operation on the parent. Note that Trigger.old will be needed as the parent's ID doesn't exist in Trigger.new

**Not an option - Workflow**

There is [no triggering of workflow (or process flows) on delete DML event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75728/can-one-start-a-process-on-record-delete)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Maybe in some future releases they would bring some alternative to this.